# Hibernate Error in Weblogic 12c Deployment

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a war in Weblogic 12c and results in the following error:

> : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class org.hibernate.AnnotationException

What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your war file misses some jar file. So check your classpath or `.bash_profile`. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) this for a better explanation.